# ESLint: App.js (22:21) Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: android, react-native, expo

The error:

```
ESLint: App.js (22:21) Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"
  20 |     export default function App() {
  21 |   
> 22 |     constructor(props){
     |                     ^
  23 |     super(props)
  24 | 
  25 |     this.state = ({ (null)
```

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content, Header, Form, Input, Item, Button, Label, } from 'native-base';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyB387ecmvoIcHvboydLrxL_vwBJqWHhXGw",
authDomain: "shootgeorgiaapp.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://shootgeorgiaapp.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "shootgeorgiaapp",
storageBucket: "shootgeorgiaapp.appspot.com"
};

if (!firebase.apps.length){
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default function App() {

constructor(props){
super(props)

 this.state = ({
   email:'',
  password:''
 })
}

signUpUser = (email,password) =>{
    try{

   if(this.state.password.length<6){
     alert("გთხოვთ მიუთთოთ 6-ზე მეტ ციფრიანი პაროლი")
    return;
   }

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)


 }
 catch(error){
   console.log(error.toString())
 }
}

logInUser = (email,password) =>{

}

return (
 <Container style={styles.container}>
  <Form>
      <Image 
      style={{height:170 , width:170, alignItems: 'center',}}
      source={require('./img/logo.png')}
      />

    <Item floatingLabel> 
      <Label>Email</Label>
      <Input
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
      />
    </Item>

    <Item floatingLabel> 
      <Label>Password</Label>
      <Input
      secureTextEntry={true}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
      />
    </Item>

  <Button style={{marginTop:10} }
  full 
  rounded
  success
  onPress={() => this.logInUser(this.state.email,this.state.password)}
  >
    <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Log in</Text>
  </Button>

  <Button style={{marginTop:10} }
  full 
  rounded
  primary
  onPress={() => this.signUpUser(this.state.email,this.state.password)}
  >
    <Text style={{color:'white'}}>Sign in</Text>
  </Button>
  </Form>
</Container>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
justifyContent: 'center',
padding: 10,
},
});
```

I tried thousands of things but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

your declaring a function 'App' and treating it as a class. A simple solution is you use classes instead

```
    export default class App extends Component{
// 
}
```

in order to inherit what you're looking for.

Security flag: don't post your api keys anywhere in the internet or sensitive information

Comment: hey , Thanks for answer. its working but now there are more errors like 
 `51 |
  52 |   return (
> 53 |     <Container style={styles.container}>
     |     ^
  54 |       <Form>
  55 |           <Image
  56 |           style={{height:170 , width:170, alignItems: 'center',}}`                                                          this one

Comment: can you send the actual error message? I see only a piece of code.